# how to validate a textbox for specific pattern in Windows form c#

Tags: c#, textbox

I want to validate a Textbox for a specific input pattern that contains Number, dot & plus singh only. 
for example.

50.4+50.6+60.7+80.4
etc...

I want user can input only in this pattern because at last I want to plus this all value separated by plus singh. So it is necessary for a user that he follow this pattern.

please any body give me solution for this.
I am working in c# Windows form application.

Comment: This won't be far off [msdn's numeric textbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms229644%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but again.. what have you tried?

Comment: As the others have said, show some examples. However, you might want to look at Regular Expressions to match the data.[Regex.Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a KeyPress event:

```
private void CheckInput(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure only digits, . and + 
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.' && e.KeyChar != '+')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    // Make sure . is in correct places only
    else if (e.KeyChar == '.')
    {
        for (int i = textBox1.SelectionStart - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text[i] == '.')
            {                       
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text[i] == '+') break;
        }
    }
    // Make sure character before + is a digit
    else if (e.KeyChar == '+' 
        && !char.IsDigit(textBox1.Text[textBox1.SelectionStart - 1]))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```